# Convert ostream to iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, producer-consumer

I have two functions, let's call them `producer(std::ostream& output)` and `consumer(std::istream& input)`, and I need to link the output of producer into the consumer. Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
std::stringstream temp;
producer(temp);
consumer(temp);
```

This has two and a half obvious disadvantages. First, the smaller problem for me, is memory usage. The producer generates about 20MB of data and this all has to be stored. The larger problem is speed. The consumer often needs to read only a few bytes from the input stream, but the producer needs to generate all. Also this wouldn't work on potentially infinite streams generated by the producer.

Is there any magic adapter thingie I could use instead of the `stringstream` that would only buffer minimal needed ammount of data and then switch between producer and consumer?

I had an idea (very non specific one :-) ) that this kind of coroutine stuff could probably be somehow done with `setjmp` and `longjmp`, but I've never worked with these functions and I have a feeling that there will be some problems with this.

I'm asking this question only out of curiosity and because I like simple looking solutions. I know I can solve this by converting producer from function directly to istream.

Edit: The behavior of my hypotetical adapter is something like this:

1. let producer run until it writes some bytes to its ostream, buffer the data
2. pause the producer, switch to consumer
3. let the consumer run until it reads the buffered data
4. pause the consumer, switch to producer
5. goto 1

There should be no need for threads in here.

Comment: Threads? … https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem (Also, the question title is **completely** unrelated to the problem).

Comment: Your problem is not quite clear. Are you running as a singleton process or in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Um how can producer know it only needs to generate few bytes, prior to calling consumer in a sequential run? If you can make it happen then you can read only as much as you need to do. If you call it in a loop, you can maybe have a static buffer in producer, produce data once, and then only feed it in subsequent calls. I am not completely sure what do you expect though. A some kind of proxy object as `temp` that would "lazy-produce" data ?

Comment: It's a single process.

Comment: Well ... what I'd really like to have is some type of coroutine, similar to python's yield keyword.

Comment: I believe that pythons generators, are "some kind of proxies that lazy-generate the data". You could make `temp` something like a generator, set it up in `producer` and then consume it in `consumer`. But I doubt there is something similar in the standard that would suit this purpose, and I am not sure if it will look nice and be nice to implement by hand. It all depends how does producer work. IMO in the end it would look like a object with call-back routine for actual producing data, and `producer` would just set it up or like a `consumer(producer())` call. Maybe someone wiser will know.

Comment: the `consumer(producer())` version is very close to rewriting the producer to be a subclass of `istream`. What I'm imagining is having the switch hidden in the operators `<<` and `>>` of the adapter.

Comment: Too unclear to answer. The solution entirely depends on _specifics_. Generally, though, try producing less data at a time then shove the whole thing in a loop.